# Reference for the value of the axial vector coupling constant, $g_A$

Tags: physical-constants, weak-interaction

[This paper](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.60.053003) (I don't know if it is available for free or not) defines the axial-vector coupling constant (a constant important in calculations involving the weak interaction) as $g=1.26$.  My advisor and I, however, both remember the value of the axial-vector coupling constant as being negative.  I am trying to verify this but cannot find any references that do so.  I would appreciate any links to references that measure/derive the value of the axial-vector coupling constant.

Note 1: $g$ as used in the paper I linked is, I believe, more commonly referred to as $g_A$, as far as I remember.

Note 2: In the paper I link $g$ is always squared so the sign of $g$ does not matter, which may be why the authors dropped the negative sign in their paper, if indeed $g$ is negative.

Comment: Without having looked at the paper I can say that Paul Vogel and John Beacom are *big* names in the neutrino community. I'd be pretty surprised to learn that they were way off base.

Comment: Also, a paper by my advisor uses a similar value ($1.2695 \pm 0.0029$) and cites *S. Eidelman et al. (Particle Data Group), Phys. Lett. B592, 1 (2004)* for the value. The value of $g_A$ comes in linearly, so the sign would matter. By now the 2004 value might be superseded, but I'd look in the Review of Particle Physics for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0370-2693(97)00880-0) quotes a positive value for $g_A$, namely $g_A\simeq 1.26$.

[This paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/9904166) quotes a value for the axial-vector coupling constant for protons, $c_A$, defined in terms of $g_A$ as $c_A = -g_A = -1.26$, which also implies a positive value for $g_A$.

dmckee in the comments to the question points out that the [Particle Data Group](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2004/reviews/contents_sports.html) also quote a positive value for $g_A$.

Thus, $g_A$ is positive.

Answer (score 1):

The sign of the axial vector coupling $g_A$ is ultimately a matter of convention. You just need to define it such that your formulas which depend on the nuclear current are consistent. The overall sign of the matrix element is arbitrary due to the arbitrary phase, but you do need to make sure that interference terms are consistent (e.g., first forbidden beta decay matrix elements, or one-plus-two-body Gamow-Teller matrix elements).

My advisor also recalls $g_A= -1.27$, which I would go with.
Some other examples: the older text "H. Behrens and J. Janecke, Numerical Tables for Beta-Decay and Electron Capture (Springer-Verlag, 1969)." puts their formulas in terms of the variable $\lambda =  - g_A/g_V = +1.25$. Also the 2020 version of the particle data group gives the baryon decay parameter $\lambda = g_A/g_V = -1.2754$. Both examples where it is negative.

In my experience I have seen the measured value stated as positive in the text of papers, but in the formulas they use it as negative, so be careful. Often though the sign does not matter, because again physical quantities depend on squared matrix elements, and simple cases like the one-body Gamow-Teller operator are then proportional to $g_A^2$.